# Firefox Network Monitor Request Size

Tags: firefox, network-traffic, firefox-developer-tools

Firefox Network Monitor lists a column for the size of a request, but it does not specify if it's the total size of outbound and inbound traffic, or just the outbound.

Is there another way to measure a request's outbound traffic size (POST data + headers + cookies) that does not involve installing Wireshark?

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no way to see the full size - I've logged [this bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1160611) to track the issue. I think it's a good idea.